# Error using Template HTML in Custom Dialog Box: "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again"

Tags: google-apps-script, customdialog, html-templates

I'm trying to add to a sheet a custom dialog box created from HTML template, and nothing I do has any outcome but this error:  "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again."

To eliminate all chances of error on my part, or conflict with anything I'd already written, I put aside my project, and started over with a blank spreadsheet. I added to it absolutely nothing but the code Google recommends at
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
  .createTemplateFromFile('Index')
  .evaluate();
}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello, World! The time is <?= new Date() ?>.
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm STILL getting the error. Apart from a very simple Custom Menu that enables you to invoke this function, there isn't a thing in my code apart from this function and HTML copied and pasted from Google Developers. I have tried some of the other examples on that page, but no matter what function I try, the result is this same cryptic error message.

Here is the Google Sheet; see if you can get that function "Do Get" to work:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RpbYryy0El80oj-07Q21cbtRr8gPDCjrwPbHbBF4Zr0/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1):

### For displaying a [custom dialog](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_dialogs) you cannot directly return the html content.

You need to use the method [showModalDialog(userInterface, title)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui?hl=en#showmodaldialoguserinterface,-title).

Sample:

```js
function onOpen() {
  customMenu();
}

function customMenu () {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('')
  .addItem('Dialog','showDialog')
  .addToUi();
}


function showDialog() {
  var dialog = doGet();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(dialog, 'This is the dialog version of the WebApp');
}

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
  .createTemplateFromFile('Index')
  .evaluate();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works fine now! What a misleading error message, though; you would think Google could do a better job at that than to tell you to try later what can't possibly work.